# Invoking a new CMD window from WSL without waiting

Tags: bash, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible *(without using a terminal emulator)* to invoke a new CMD (or bash) instance in a new Window from within WSL, without having the calling command wait on the new CMD?

The usual way to invoke a Windows-side program (that is not already on the PATH) from within WSL is using the new interop capabilities in WSL. So if I wanted to open a PDF, for example, I could do:

```
cmd.exe /c start "" "filename with spaces.pdf"
```

which works - my Windows-side PDF viewer opens up the file and the command returns.

I would expect these to work the same way, but they don't:

```
cmd.exe /c start "" cmd.exe
cmd.exe /c start "" wsl.exe
```

That is, they do open a new window with the new CMD/WSL shell, but the commands wait for the new shell to exit before returning. Why does this happen, and is there anyway around it?

<sub>(I also tried using the `/NEWWINDOW` flag of `start`, to no avail.)</sub>

Comment: I probably don't understand your question but try this: create a shortcut to cmd and start it this way `start "" cmd.exe.lnk`

Comment: @somebadhat You're absolutely right, that was the key! It required a bit of a hack to get WSL to open in the right worknig directory, but I needed the shortcut method to get it to open in a new window (and return). I'll post my full solution at some point, but thank you for this! :)